# How to Add .gif format stickers to I message app in Swift 3?

Tags: animation, browser, swift3, gif, mssticker

I stucked with one problem can you solve me?

Actually I'm implementing custom sticker pack for imessage app. For that I implemented all the things its working fine but only one case.

So if I add .jpg or .png format files its displaying and sending perfectly. If i add .gif format images for stickers it's not animating while displaying time.

Displaying purpose i used collection view `MSStickerView`.

My code is:

```
func LoadStickers()
{


    for i in 1...5 {
        if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "nature\(i)", withExtension: "gif") {
            do {
                let sticker = try MSSticker(contentsOfFileURL: url, localizedDescription: "")
                stickers.append(sticker)
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
```

These are my collection view delegates:

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {

    return 1
}



func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return stickers.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "StickerPackCell", for: indexPath) as! FemaleStickerPackViewCell

    // Configure the cell

    cell.femaleStickerPack.sticker = stickers[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

This is `UICollectionViewCell`:

```
class StickerViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
 @IBOutlet var femaleStickerPack: MSStickerView!

}
```

This is extension:

```
extension UIViewController
{
   func addTo(appViewController host:MSMessagesAppViewController)
   {
    willMove(toParentViewController: host)
    host.addChildViewController(self)
    view.frame = host.view.bounds
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    host.view.addSubview(view)

    view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: host.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: host.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    view.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: host.view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    view.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: host.view.rightAnchor).isActive = true

    didMove(toParentViewController: host)

   }
}
```

So I want to store .gif format stickers can anybody help me please I tried lot of ways but I failed to get.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can anybody help me please

Comment: can anybody help me please i'm waiting for your responses

Comment: Can you send it right ?